# getting a socket.gaierror Error 2 when using an actual hostname defined in /etc/hosts, but do not get error with localhost

Tags: python, sockets

I have copied simple server/client python programs to test some socket communications.
If host is defined as 'localhost' or '', they work.
If I substitute the actual hostname in /etc/hosts, they fail with the socket.gaierror 2.
socket.gethostname() returns the correct value
as does 'hostname' on the command line.

Here is the server code that fails

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
A simple echo server
"""

import socket
import sys

host = ''
port = 50000
backlog = 5
size = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()

print( " using host [%s] " % (host) )
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(backlog)
while 1:
    client, address = s.accept()
    data = client.recv(size)
    print( data )
    if data:
        client.send(data)
    client.close()
```

and here is the client program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
A simple echo client
"""

import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 50000
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
s.connect((host,port))
s.send('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(size)
s.close()
print( 'Received:', data )
```

This is the actual output from the server.py while using the gethostname() call.

```
using host [HP-linux] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 18, in <module>
    s.bind((host,port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Like I said, if I comment out the 'gethostname() calls, they work.
I have not been able to find any posts about gaierrors that have answers that work to solve this issue.
This running on SuSE Linux 13.1, and python2.7.

Thanks

This issue was resolved by adding an alias to the /etc/hosts file.
No rational answer as to why this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Binding the server on hostname you're actualy binding it on local address, this is because normally there's a line in `/etc/hosts` like this 127.0.1.1 somehostname, this is to use `lo` iface instead of `eth` on the same machine for optimization reasons. If you want to accept connections from all interfaces use '0.0.0.0' instead.

Answer (score 0):

I simply did these steps.

Ran command:

```
hostname
```

Say it returned me a value 'yourHostName'

Make an entry in your /etc/hosts file as follows.

```
127.0.0.1 yourHostName localhost
```

Reference for this information is : format of /etc/hosts file. Which you can [see here.](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fh%2Fhosts.html)